# How to enable reCAPTCHA v3 in Opencart 2x?

Tags: recaptcha, opencart2.x, recaptcha-v3

I want to use reCAPTCHA v3 in Opencart 2x.

As Opencart 2 supports reCAPTCHA by default i need to modify some files but I'm not such a coding guy.

I found this code in /controller/captcha/google_captcha.php

```
class ControllerCaptchaGoogleCaptcha extends Controller {
    public function index($error = array()) {
        $this->load->language('captcha/google_captcha');

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['entry_captcha'] = $this->language->get('entry_captcha');

        $this->document->addScript('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js');

        if (isset($error['captcha'])) {
            $data['error_captcha'] = $error['captcha'];
        } else {
            $data['error_captcha'] = '';
        }

        $data['site_key'] = $this->config->get('google_captcha_key');

        $data['route'] = $this->request->get['route']; 

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/captcha/google_captcha.tpl')) {
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/captcha/google_captcha.tpl', $data);
        } else {
            return $this->load->view('default/template/captcha/google_captcha.tpl', $data);
        }
    }

    public function validate() {
        $this->load->language('captcha/google_captcha');

        $recaptcha = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($this->config->get('google_captcha_secret')) . '&response=' . $this->request->post['g-recaptcha-response'] . '&remoteip=' . $this->request->server['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha, true);

        if (!$recaptcha['success']) {
            return $this->language->get('error_captcha');
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to modify this file?

Answer (score -1):

Answer: don't. Google's reCAPTCHA is annoying. Instead read this and use the extension posted in the comments that provides 100% spam protection and is invisible: https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/why-enable-captcha-what-is-advanced-captcha-and-how-does-it-prev/

Comment: $130 is a way too much I'm willing to pay for OC extension when average price on OC marketplace is between $20-$30. Especially when there are plenty of free alternatives. Also I don't see any demos, any information about how it works, nothing!!! I'm using reCAPTCHA V3 on wordpress and it works very well, they now allow you to hide the badge so it's quite good solution.

Comment: Thank you Husein for your valuable feedback, a lot of work went in to this extension to make it 100% bot proof but we have taken your feedback on board and reduced the price to $50.

Comment: Thanks will look at your plugin if I can't find proper solution!

Comment: Well this is a proper solution, and a better one than both the default and Google reCAPTCHA.